# Intellij Idea Plugin get class-file of virtual file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing an Intellij extension and tehrefore i need to know the location of the class file of a specific virtual file. I'm loading the virtual file the following way:

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getProject() == null) return;
    FileEditorManager manager = FileEditorManager.getInstance(e.getProject());
    VirtualFile files[] = manager.getSelectedFiles();
    //Any files open?
    if (files.length == 0 || !files[0].getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java"))
        return;
    analyse(files[0]);
}
```

Inside the analyse-function I want to show the content of the class file in a gui.

Is it possible to receive the class file from j given java-file or the psi-tree?

Comment: Do you want to show the compiled .class file for the respective .java file?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FilenameIndex.getFilesByName()` method to get the .class file. Since you know the name of the .java file, you can use that to derive the .class file name.

But I don't think it will work since .class files are in target directory and IDEA does not index that directory. You can use `VfsUtil.collectChildrenRecursively()` method to get al the files in the **target** directory and later filter out the .class file you need.